# Como retornar numa consulta um carácter especial

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia!

Pode ser simples minha dúvida, mas estou iniciando em SQL Server ainda, então gostaria de saber como retornar num select um carácter especial.

Pois como podem ver, existe a presença de uma aspa simples no campo Nat_Rec e não posso colocar num like creio eu, já tentei de várias formas, mas não consegui filtrar os registros com a aspa somente. Se puderem me ajudar com esse problema, agradeço desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Evite colocar o código de programa ou de consulta dentro de uma imagem. Coloque em texto mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O caractere a que se refere não se denomina “aspa simples” mas sim ápice, embora no dia a dia o confundamos com o [apóstrofo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3strofo). Em termos gráficos há uma diferença sutil entre ápice e apóstrofo.

Na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) o ápice possui o valor decimal de 39. Há algumas formas de selecioná-lo, sendo uma delas através da função [char()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql):

```
-- código #1
SELECT colunas
  from PC_TabM410
  where Nat_Rec = char(39);
```

Comment: Então... não sabia ao certo qual o nome do caractere, mas agradeço por me esclarecer também isso. Já sobre a consulta, era exatamente o que eu procurava, também me ajudou ainda mais por me mostrar a Tabela ASCII, pois eu não tinha conhecimento que existia. Agradeço muito, foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: @DaniloVilhena No idioma inglês existem expressões como _single quoted_ e _double quoted_. No idioma português os sinais utilizados corresponderiam ao apóstrofo e às aspas. Mas, em tempos pretéritos da computação, algum "tradutor" criou o termo "aspas simples" porque provavelmente não conhecia o apóstrofo. :(
Aliás, o mesmo "tradutor" criou termos como _deletar_ (temos o apagar), _updatar_ (temos o atualizar) etc etc.  :(

Answer (score 0):

`select * from PC_Tab410 where MesAno='08/2018' AND Nas_Rec='*'`

Onde * é o caracter que queres. Aconselho a copiares o caracter mesmo da base de dados para esse querry por causa da formatação

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, mas não era exatamente o que procurava saber...amigo